Real category with addition as coproduct and multiplication as product
Is there a category with objects as real numbers such that the coproduct/product of two objects is their addition/multiplication of them.
I tried to build one myself, imagining a special transitive binary relation on the reals. I'm starting conjecturing that maybe $\wedge$ is not the right composition of relations as morphisms.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Would an answer showing that there is only one such category (the trivial one) satisfy you?

It's not clear to me what the trivial is so I would definitely appreciate your answer

You might be interested in this question on MO which just focuses on multiplication

I will first give a proof sketch of a little lemma and then use that to show that any category with objects as real numbers and coproduct as addition is just the trivial category (the category with only one object and only one morphism).
Lemma :  If $X$ and $Y$ are objects in a category such that $X+Y$ (the coproduct) is initial, then $X,Y$ are initial.
Proof sketch : Let $Z$ be any object. Since $X+Y$ is initial, there exists a unique morphism $f:X+Y\to Z$. Now, there are morphisms $\iota_X:X\to X+Y$ and $\iota_Y:Y\to X+Y$ and hence we can construct morphims $f\iota_x:X\to Z$ and $f\iota_Y:Y\to Z$. The universal property of the coproduct will show these maps are unique.

Once we have this lemma, we can prove our original claim as follows. Consider an object $x$. Now $-x$ is also an object, and we have $x+(-x)=0$. Since $0$ is initial (by taking the empty sum), by the lemma we have that $x,-x$ are initial. In particular $x$ is initial. Since $x$ was arbitrary, every object in this category is initial and hence all the objects are isomorphic (uniquely!), so the category is just the terminal category.
